# how to load two custom UITableViewCell without xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have two `UITableViewCell` class and I want to load this two `UITableViewCell` in my `UITableView`.
I know that when I want to load one `UITableViewCell` without xib file in my `UITableView` I use this code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [table registerClass:[SecondViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if(indexPath.row == 0){
       SecondViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
       cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
       cell.Email.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"sdasdd@gmail.com"];
       cell.Address.text = txt;
       return cell;
    }
    else{

       //load second cell
    }
}
```

now I want to how to load two `UITableViewCell` in my `UITableView`

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [table registerClass:[FirstViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    [table registerClass:[SecondViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if(indexPath.row == 0){
       SecondViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2 forIndexPath:indexPath];
       cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
       cell.Email.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"sdasdd@gmail.com"];
       cell.Address.text = txt;
       return cell;
    }
    else{
       FirstViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
       cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
       return cell;
    }

    return nil;
}
```